# Solving a diffusion equation

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve a particular diffusion equation with NO boundaries (see eqn. (2.10) in: [*Ann. Rev. Astron. Astrophys.* 19:137-62 (1981).](http://astronomy.nju.edu.cn/~chenpf/c/courses/fluid/pringle81.pdf)) with `nu = cost`.

$$\partial\Sigma/\partial t=3R^{-1}\partial/\partial R \{R^{1/2}\partial/\partial R[\nu\Sigma R^{1/2}]\}$$

I use this code to simplify the equation:

```
pde = D[s[x, t], t] == (3/2)*D[s[x, t], x] + (3/4)*x^-2*D[s[x, t], {x, 2}] - 1/(4*x);
mu = 0.5;
sigma = 0.05;
```

and to solve the equation (which by choosing `nu = cost` becomes a linear diffusion partial equation) I use this:

```
 sol = 
  DSolve[{pde, s[x, 0] == Exp[-(x - mu)^2/(2*sigma^2)]/Sqrt[2*Pi*sigma^2]}, s[x, t], {x, t}]
```

with a particular choice of the initial function (a gaussian function).

But when I try

```
Plot3D[s[x, t] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, Automatic}]
```

to plot the results, which should reproduce Figure 1 in the paper above, I get a lot of errors and I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you sure DSolve is being able to solve your equation?

Comment: I think is it possible because it's a linear PDE, in the case is it impossible can NDSolve resolve it?

Comment: The equation is solvable in terms of the [`WhittakerM`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhittakerM.html) function, but I think you should look at other answers here, on Mathematica SE, regarding the usage of `NDSolve` handling singularities, different step sizes, different methods, etc.